# MySQL returns no results when searching a column

Tags: mysql

Here is the command I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM pos WHERE word = 'accelerator' OR id = 3;
```

This returns:

```
'3', 'accelerator\r', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

But when I use:

```
SELECT * FROM pos WHERE word = 'accelerator';
```

I get `NULL` as response.

Here is my table structure

[image]

Comment: so? there are no rows where `word ='accelerator'`, maybe you want `SELECT * FROM pos WHERE trim(BOTH '\r' word) = 'accelerator';`?

Comment: Works as designed, no?  `'accelerator\r'` is different from `'accelerator'`

Comment: It returns `NULL` because there are no rows found. You search for `'accelerator'` but column value is `'accelerator\r'` (note the `\r`). If you want search by part of string then use `word LIKE '%accelerator%'` (the percent symbol represents any number of any characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'accelerator' is different from 'accelerator\r'. So it seems you have inserted the data without stripping them. To verify use:

```
SELECT * FROM pos WHERE word = 'accelerator\r'
```

It should return the row

Answer (score 0):

```
'accelerator\r' !== 'accelerator'
```

You may be instead thinking of using `LIKE` so:

```
SELECT * FROM pos WHERE word LIKE '%accelerator%';
```

would return the correct results for you.

Answer (score 0):

In `'accelerator\r'` notice the `\r` at the end of the string.

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM pos WHERE word LIKE 'accelerator%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your `where` clause:

```
WHERE word = 'accelerator' OR id = 3;
```

this is true if at least one of the two operands is true. The condition is true for the given record, therefore at least one of the operands is true for it. Let's take a look at your other where clause:

```
WHERE word = 'accelerator';
```

this one is more strict and does not yield the given record. Using the second `where` clause you see there is no row with `'accelerator'` as the value for `word`, however, you have found a record using your first `where` clause, which has `'acclerator\r'` as its `word`, which differs from `'accelerator'`, but its `id` is `3`, so, according to your first `where` clause, the record fulfills your condition, as at least one of the operands of the `OR` is true.